How can I plot the last value in this for loop iteration?
In this function, I've initialised lastBarHigh, which is to get the last iteration value, and I am returning this value for entire function, so that i can see my value on display window, but instead, it was printing, 0.00 as a value here in data window. I've assigned value on for loop, but for this entire function, in return it was having a type of na.
Here's my code:
drawOrderBlocks(bool internal = false) =>       
    float lastBarHigh = na 
    array<orderBlock> orderBlocks = internal ? internalOrderBlocks : swingOrderBlocks
    orderBlocksSize = orderBlocks.size()

    if orderBlocksSize > 0        
        maxOrderBlocks                      = internal ? internalOrderBlocksSizeInput : swingOrderBlocksSizeInput
        array<orderBlock> parsedOrdeBlocks  = orderBlocks.slice(0, math.min(maxOrderBlocks,orderBlocksSize))
        array<box> b_oxes                   = internal ? internalOrderBlocksBoxes : swingOrderBlocksBoxes        

        for [index,eachOrderBlock] in parsedOrdeBlocks
            lastBarHigh := eachOrderBlock.barHigh
            
            orderBlockColor = styleInput == MONOCHROME ? (eachOrderBlock.bias == BEARISH ? color.new(MONO_BEARISH,80) : color.new(MONO_BULLISH,80)) : internal ? (eachOrderBlock.bias == BEARISH ? internalBearishOrderBlockColor : internalBullishOrderBlockColor) : (eachOrderBlock.bias == BEARISH ? swingBearishOrderBlockColor : swingBullishOrderBlockColor)

            box b_ox        = b_oxes.get(index)
            b_ox.set_top_left_point(    chart.point.new(eachOrderBlock.barTime,na,eachOrderBlock.barHigh))
            b_ox.set_bottom_right_point(chart.point.new(last_bar_time,na,eachOrderBlock.barLow))        
            b_ox.set_border_color(      internal ? na : orderBlockColor)
            b_ox.set_bgcolor(           orderBlockColor)
    
    lastBarHigh

float lastHigh = drawOrderBlocks()

plot(na(lastHigh)?0:lastHigh,title = "barHigh",color =color.red,display = display.data_window)


Are you sure your loop is executed? Did you try to debug it with log.*() functions? Maybe share a minimal reproducible example so we can test.

ok, everything went good, but can i reverse for loop here, so i can get first iterated lastBarHigh value here in this for loop, please

You don't need a loop for that. Just get the first element of the array.
